# Can I unlock the "You Saved Science" achievement in split-screen co-op?

Tags: xbox-360, achievements, portal-2

The achievement description states:

> Complete all test chambers in all courses of co-op.

Can this be completed in split-screen to unlock this achievement, or does it have to be done over Xbox Live?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This achievement, along with most other co-op achievements in Portal 2, can be obtained from either split-screen or online play.

The only achievements which require online play appear to be [Friends List With Benefits](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/portal-2/achievement/51226-Friends-List-With-Benefits.html) and [Professor Portal](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/portal-2/achievement/51218-Professor-Portal.html).